# How to extends function that have observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have two functions: `save` and `publish`, and they triggered by buttons.

The logic inside publish function should execute AFTER save execution. So I called `save` function and use it inside `publish` function.

The problem is I call to `subscribe` function inside `save` to invoke the observable because otherwise it will not works.

And if I return the `observable` from `save` I can't so subscribe again..

So any ideas how can I solve this problem?

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: `
    <h1>my app</h1>

    <button (click)="save()">save</button>
    <button (click)="publish()">publish</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "CodeSandbox";

  save() {
    of('whatever I can call http or service here..').subscribe((r) => {
      console.log("my save logic here...");
    });
  }

  publish() {
    this.save();

    console.log('this logic should be AFTER save observable complete.');
  }
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-golick-yrwu6?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)

I think I expect to something like that:

```
  save() {
    return of("whatever I can call http or service here..").subscribe((r) => {
      console.log("my save logic here...");
    });
  }

  publish() {
    this.save().subscribe(r => {
      console.log("this logic should be AFTER save observable complete.");

    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not subscribe in `save` function. Create one function, which will return `observable` that will make save request and call it in `save()` and `publish()` functions.

```js
export class AppComponent {

  private saveDataRequest() {
    // in real example you should return http.post(....)
    return of('whatever I can call http or service here..');
  }

  save() {
    this.saveDataRequest().subscribe((r) => {
      console.log("my save logic here...");
    });
  }

  publish() {
    this.saveDataRequest().subscribe((r) => {
      console.log('this logic should be AFTER save observable complete.');
    });


  }
}
```

Comment: no. whatever the function save does I want to do it in publish as well. I mean the logic INSIDE the subscribe to be execute also in publish function. I also don't want to duplicate my functions.

Comment: @JonSud seems I misunderstood your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pipe` and rxjs operators after an observable to execute code after the execution of the observable. You can then return the new observable.

I also recommand you to use sync function to handle click events. You can subscribe in those sync functions.

```js
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: `
    <h1>my app</h1>

    <button (click)="onSaveButtonClicked()">save</button>
    <button (click)="onPublishButtonClicked()">publish</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "CodeSandbox";

  private save(): Observable<any> {
    return of('whatever I can call http or service here..').pipe(
            tap((r) => {
                console.log("my save logic here...");
            })
        );
  }

  private publish(): Observable<any> {
    return this.save().pipe(
            tap(() => {
                console.log('this logic should be AFTER save observable complete.');
            });
        )

  }

    public onSaveButtonClicked():void {
        this.save().subscribe();
    }

    public onPublishButtonClicked():void {
        this.publish.subscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: this solution makes `save` and `publish` to duplicate. think if I have a lot of functions this way

Comment: You could also reference all of your buttons and programmatically subscribe to a function when the click event is thown. But it is a good practice to separate your logic and the click function.